# Adding Cart Items to the Database and retrieving

Tags: android, mysql, cart, shopping-cart

I have three tables in mySQL namely user, restaurants, cartlist.

here user table is for saving the user details.
restaurant table is for saving the meal details, price and quantity.
cartlist is to add the restaurant details.
Now when the specific user login to the app, I want the cartlist items of specific user added to the list. but Im getting the details of whole users who added items to the cart.

```
show.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM restaurants";
            SQLiteDatabase database = DatabaseManager.getInstance().openDatabase();
            Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    ProductModel productModel = new ProductModel();
                    productModel.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));

                    productModel.setName(cursor.getString(1));
                    productModel.setMealname(cursor.getString(2));
                    productModel.setMealprice(cursor.getString(3));
                    productModel.setMealqty(cursor.getString(4));

                    products.add(productModel);

                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }

            cursor.close();
            DatabaseManager.getInstance().closeDatabase();

            adapter = new ProductAdapter(ProductList.this, R.layout.activity_cartlistview, products);
            listview.setAdapter(adapter);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
```

Carttable:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_checkout);

    lv_checkout = findViewById(R.id.lv_checkout);
    tv_totalamount = findViewById(R.id.tv_totalamount);
    btn_checkouttopayment = findViewById(R.id.btn_checkouttopayment);

    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM carttable";
    SQLiteDatabase database = DatabaseManager.getInstance().openDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            ProductModel productModel = new ProductModel();
            productModel.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));

            productModel.setName(cursor.getString(1));
            productModel.setMealname(cursor.getString(2));
            productModel.setMealprice(cursor.getString(3));
            productModel.setMealqty(cursor.getString(4));
            productModel.setMealtotal((Double.parseDouble(cursor.getString(3)) * Double.parseDouble(cursor.getString(4)) + ""));

            products.add(productModel);

        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    double totalPrices = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < products.size(); i++) {

        totalPrices += Double.parseDouble(products.get(i).getMealtotal());
    }

    tv_totalamount.setText("Total Amount to be Paid : " + totalPrices + "");
    cursor.close();
    DatabaseManager.getInstance().closeDatabase();

    adapter = new ProductAdapter(this, R.layout.activity_cartlistview, products);
    lv_checkout.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

what are the changed to be done to the query? Let me knw guys.TIA!

Comment: Where is `cartlist` in your code? I think you should query from the cartlist if exists, instead of `restaurants`

Comment: added code@Tura

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because The query you are running is going to the Restaurant table and getting all the Records from It. From what I can understand, Cartlist the name of table in which a user will input the  details of a particular restaurant. So Right now, you are calling all the records from Restaurant table which will give you the list regardless of who added it. 
You might want to change the query to something like

```
SELECT restaurant_name FROM cartlist WHERE userName = selected_User;
```

Now you have the restaurant name. Save these and use it on query.

```
SELECT * FROM restaurants WHERE restaurantsName = selected_restaurant_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
do {
        ProductModel productModel = new ProductModel();
        productModel.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));

        productModel.setName(cursor.getString(1));
        productModel.setMealname(cursor.getString(2));
        productModel.setMealprice(cursor.getString(3));
        productModel.setMealqty(cursor.getString(4));
        productModel.setMealtotal((Double.parseDouble(cursor.getString(3)) * Double.parseDouble(cursor.getString(4)) + ""));

        products.add(productModel);

    }
```

Add a constructor to your model class and inject in. Saves a few lines of code/readability.

```
do {
    products.add( new ProductModel(
    Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)), 
    cursor.getString(1),
    cursor.getString(2),
    cursor.getString(3),
    cursor.getString(4),
    }
```

The line: `productModel.setMealtotal((Double.parseDouble(cursor.getString(3)) * Double.parseDouble(cursor.getString(4)) + ""));`
 seems to contain a simple relationship where the "Meal total = mean quantity * meal price" which could be done in the constructor as well...it is a constant algorithm and part of the model.

Here is the model (I have added @Data using lombok which makes all the getters and setters when being compiled)

```
import lombok.Data;

@Data
public class ProductModel {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String mealName;
    private int mealPrice;
    private int mealQuantity;
    private int mealTotal;

    //Constructor...i.e. "new ProductModel(field1,field2...)" 
    public ProductModel(int id, String name, String mealName, int mealPrice, int mealQuantity) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.mealName = mealName;
        this.mealPrice = mealPrice;
        this.mealQuantity = mealQuantity;
        this.mealTotal = mealPrice * mealQuantity;
    }
}
```